# Write own code for Hybrid Mobile apps to communicate with native code

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

One of the ways to make hybrid apps communicate with native code is to use readymade frameworks like PhoneGap..

Is there any way by which we can do that on our own (and not use libraries like PhoneGap)?
If yes, what exactly would we need to handle ? Would we need to create a JS only library or both JS and native code based API and expose it ?

Any basic/theoretical example explaining the code to be required would be great..

Comment: Probably [this documentation about Building Web Apps in WebView](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) may be useful. Edit: I didn't notice the `ios` tag. This one is for Android only though.

Comment: Actually the article covers web apps...i wanted to know about hybrid apps...

Comment: Yes, you possible. On Android [read](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-interface/) and IOS [read](http://ramkulkarni.com/blog/calling-objective-c-function-from-javascript-in-ios-applications/).